# ¿De dónde viene la expresión "el útimo grito" para indicar la tendencia o moda más reciente?

Tags: etimología, expresiones

Cuando algo es una novedad, podemos decir que "es el último grito". Esta acepción viene por supuesto recogida en el DRAE

> [grito](https://dle.rae.es/grito?m=form) / último grito
>
> 1. m. Novedad sorprendente en la moda o en otros ámbitos.

Y la destaco aquí por esa referencia especial al ámbito de la moda frente a otros.

Es obvio que la voz es el principal instrumento para la comunicación (o uno de los principales), pero también es cierto que gritar para transmitir información conlleva connotaciones distintas (de ahí todas esas otras locuciones que se pueden ver en la página enlazada: *poner el grito en el cielo, a voz en grito, a grito limpio o pelado...*). todas esas otras lociones implican desesperación, dolor, rabia, etc.

La única ocasión en que me imagino un grito usado para transmitir información (distinta a esas situaciones para las que imaginamos que se pueden usar "poner el grito en el cielo, a grito limpio, etc.) sería la del [pregonero](https://dle.rae.es/pregonero?m=form):

> 2. m. y f. Empleado público que **en alta voz** da los pregones, publica y hace notorio lo que se quiere hacer saber a todos.

¿Pero entonces, por qué ese matiz de "en [el mundo] la moda" de la definición? "ser el último grito" me cuadraría como "la noticia más reciente (que nos ha dado a voces el pregonero", pero no tanto como "la **tendencia** más reciente". También puede ser que una haya evolucionado en la otra.

¿Alguien sabe de dónde viene esta expresión de "ser el último grito" en algo?

Comment: En italiano también existe "all'ultimo grido" para indicar a la última moda, pero los diccionarios indican que se trata de una traducción literal del francés. De hecho, como puedes ver en el  [*Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI23/00323.jpg), también se usa directamente el francés "dernier cri". Esto cuadra con la información que ha encontrado @Gustavson.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vamos a ver si de verdad la expresión es un galicismo, [como afirma Gustavson](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/34595/12637). La expresión *el último grito* es bastante más antigua que los casos de la década de 1970 recogidos por el trabajo de María Piedad de la Fuente. Ya en la década de 1920 se encuentran casos con el significado actual, pero no quiero adelantarme. Vamos a hacer un recorrido histórico...

Por supuesto, al principio el uso de la expresión era literal, y se solía usar como expresión del último aliento proferido en situación de angustia o dolor:

> *Un último estremecimiento de vida circuló por aquel cuerpo ya casi muerto, reunió todas sus fuerzas para incorporarse en el lecho, sus ojos brillaron con una expresión sublime de entusiasmo, último reflejo de una pasión desdichada, postrer luz de una lámpara que se apaga, primer flor que brota en un sepulcro, y cayó en brazos del joven, profiriendo entre sollozos y angustia estertorosa este último grito supremo, queja y amor al mismo tiempo, postrer adiós de un corazón que se despide de una vida donde sólo halló pesadumbres, martirio y desengaño.*
>
> Juan Díaz Covarrubias, "Gil Gómez, el insurgente: novela histórica", México (1858).

Otro ejemplo:

> *No sabemos si algún reo de muerte habrá hecho esta singular observación, pero debe ser horrible a sus oídos el último grito que ha de oír de la coliflorera que pasa atronando las calles a su lado.*
>
> Mariano José de Larra, "Un reo de muerte", 1835 (España).

Hacia finales del siglo XIX la expresión se usaba ya, curiosamente, con fines políticos, no sé si como licencia poética como para indicar las medidas de los grupos para mantenerse con vida:

> *[...] en las Cortes, se han ocupado de la concesión del Noroeste; este es el último grito de los opositores; pero esta interpelación no ha producido efecto alguno, ni dentro ni fuera del Parlamento.*
>
> Gaceta de los caminos de hierro. 29/2/1880, [página 4](http://hemerotecadigital.bne.es/issue.vm?id=0000080335&page=4&search=%22el%20%C3%BAltimo%20grito%22&lang=es).

Esta idea de "lo último que se le ha ocurrido a alguien para seguir al pie del cañón" queda incluso más patente en este texto, de un artículo titulado "El colmo del fanatismo artístico":

> *El último grito del modernismo artístico es hacer la propaganda del llamado* idioma de la música, *especie de volapuk lírico.*
>
> Revista general internacional. 7/9/1900, n.º 67, [página 6](http://hemerotecadigital.bne.es/issue.vm?id=0005379513&page=6&search=%22el%20%C3%BAltimo%20grito%22&lang=es).

O incluso este otro ejemplo, para referirse al último recurso usado por alguien que quiere dar su opinión:

> *Y hablarán también los mudos... Porque la mímica expresiva es el último grito de las mayorías indignadas.*
>
> La Correspondencia de España. 15/9/1900, n.º 15.565, [página 1](http://hemerotecadigital.bne.es/issue.vm?id=0000471316&page=1&search=%22el%20%C3%BAltimo%20grito%22&lang=es).

Sin embargo, con el tiempo la expresión comenzó a usarse en contextos algo más positivos:

> *Clau.- (Sacando un abanico en forma de revólver, de esos que se tira de la punta del cañón y sale el abanico y abriéndolo.) Pues ahí lo tienes anunciado. Revólver de estos, he repartido a millares.*
>
> *Jus.- (Leyendo en el abanico.) "El último grito de la ciencia. El pañuelo cura-catarros."*
>
> Enrique García Álvarez, "Pancho Virondo. Zarzuela en dos actos divididos en cuatro cuadros", España (1920).

Y, por supuesto, el ámbito de la moda no se escapó de ese concepto de "lo último que tengo que decir para mantenerme con vida":

> *Pero ya esta moda de la delicada afición femenina á los perros va evolucionando... El último grito, el más audaz, viene, como siempre, lanzado de Norteamérica, donde las elegantes portan pequeños cachorros de leones y de tigres con la misma naturalidad que un fox-terrier.*
>
> Anónimo. "Las fieras domesticadas", España (1924).

Y otro ejemplo:

> *¡Los franceses, locos con el Imperio! ¡París, maravilloso! ¡La Ópera, brillante! ¡Los modistos, un escándalo! ¡Pero qué lujo, qué gracia, qué esprit! Esta primavera, el último grito, los fulares estampados con rosas. Eugenia ha puesto la moda. ¡Para las rubias, admirable! ¡Tú, Carolina, estarás encantadora!*
>
> Ramón María del Valle-Inclán, "La corte de los milagros", España (1927-1931).

Entiendo que con el tiempo el ámbito de la moda fue el más beneficiado por esta expresión, aunque no el único:

> *El Banco en casa es el último grito en esto de la informatización financiera, y es que la Banca, como en tantas otras cosas, también ha sido la pionera en estos de informatizarse.*
>
> ABC, 17/11/1983 : La Banca, el sector más informatizado

A la vista de esta progresión no me queda claro que la expresión provenga del francés. No lo descarto, es posible que en francés la expresión haya sufrido una progresión similar y que ellos la usaran aplicada al ámbito de la moda antes que nosotros. Como análisis rápido, nótese este texto en francés de 1865:

> *[...] que le dernier cri de Jésus qui précéda immédiatement sa mort.*

Esto confirma el uso similar de la expresión en francés en la misma época en la que nosotros la usábamos con el mismo sentido. Y su sentido figurado aparece también en la misma época que en español, como refleja este texto de 1905:

> *D'où le dernier effort, le dernier cri de leur défense, le pamphlet dont nous nous occupons.*

O incluso este otro de 1919:

> *Il y a enfin des comités agricoles communaux, cantonaux, organisés selon le dernier cri des utopies bolchévistes [...].*

Sin embargo, no logro encontrarar en Ngram (de donde estoy sacando los textos en francés) referencias al uso de la frase en el sentido de la moda, aunque es curioso que la expresión francesa se encuentra en textos en español, referidos a la moda y anteriores a los textos expuestos. Valga como ejemplo este:

> *Habrán ustedes observado que la última moda* dernier cri, *como dicen en París ahora, y dirá dentro de algunas semanas* La Época, *es meterse cada cual donde no le llaman y en lo que no entiende.*
>
> Madrid cómico. 2/7/1887, [página 3](http://hemerotecadigital.bne.es/issue.vm?id=0002077667&page=3&search=%22dernier%20cri%22&lang=es).

Esto confirma que en Francia se usaba *dernier cri* para expresar las tendencias actuales antes que en España, a falta de buscar más documentos, y que no fue hasta más adelante cuando se comenzó a usar la traducción *último grito*. En todo caso, he preguntado en el sitio de francés por el origen exacto de la expresión *[dernier cri](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/41860/20830)* en el ámbito de las tendencias de moda. De momento el origen parece situarse en los pregoneros, que decían a voz en grito las últimas noticias (y las últimas normas a seguir), y los primeros textos que han encontrado son de finales del siglo XIX, contemporáneos de este último texto citado en español:

> *C'était le dernier cri de la mode du temps d'Antoine Avernier.* (1891)

Comment: Los ejemplos de la década de 1920 que pones son muy claros: la expresión ya se usaba con el sentido figurado entonces. Sin embargo, creo posible que la influencia francesa en los 60 contribuyera a poner la expresión de moda. Recuerdo haber visto la expresión francesa tal cual, *dernier cri*, en textos en español de esa época, y Google me da unos 1400 resultados para *el dernier cri* en castellano; el primero, curiosamente, un artículo sobre la NGLE.

Comment: @Gorpik acabo de encontrar un texto que puede arrojar un poco de luz al asunto, modifico la respuesta.

Comment: Viene del francês, dernier cri, si.

Answer (score 3):

Según [esta página](https://eprints.ucm.es/id/eprint/57364/13/MariaPiedaddelaFuente.pdf), se trata de un galicismo:

> [...] en una época en la que la expresión francesa *nouvelle vague* tenía una vigencia muy grande y una enorme influencia en lo que se refiere a cine y literatura, es lógico que aparezca dentro de un contexto que se pretende "au dernier cri" como era la moda en las
> revistas de entonces, una expresión como ésta, un tanto híbrida de forma, pero no de contenido, porque la idea que quiere transmitir es la misma de "ir a la última", "llevar puesto el último grito de moda", etc.

Hacia el final, el trabajo citado dice:

> D.L.E. 2014 (versión electrónica 23.1.)
> “último grito” se incluyó en la edición del Diccionario de 2014 (versión electrónica 23.1.) bajo la entrada “grito” en su acepción nº 1, con la siguiente definición: 1. m. Novedad sorprendente en la moda o en otros ámbitos.

A su vez, el origen de la palabra "cri" (grito) en francés proviene, de acuerdo con [esta otra página](https://vitrinelinguistique.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/index.php?id=23916), del anuncio hecho a viva voz por los mercaderes.